# Using .map instead of for loop

Tags: for-loop, react-hooks, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to use .map instead of a for loop since i've converted to hooks from class component. I've tried replacing the for(var.... with .map attributes are not being added to the objects in my array. Any help? Or maybe a better more concise way to do this in general? Thanks!

```
  const getIOLabelRules = (rulename) => {
    if (rulename != null) {
      OrderService.getIORules(passedIORule, (status, data) => {
        if (status === 200) {
          setCodeList(data);
          let showArray = [];
          let hideArray = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let tempFld2 = data[i].ioRuleFld2;
            showArray.push({
              selected: false,
              value: tempFld2,
              id: data[i].id,
            });
            hideArray.push({
              selected: false,
              value: tempFld2,
              id: data[i].id,
            });
          }
          setIoLabelsHide(hideArray);
          setIoLabelsShow(showArray);
        } else {
          console.log("here," + status, data);
        } // ToDo: handle error here
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I don't see in your example code how you're trying to use `.map`? In any case, `map` isn't the same as using a `for` loop. It iterates over an array and returns a new array based on the block of code executed against each item within the original. Perhaps you're looking for `forEach` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I replaced the for(.....) with data.map((newArr)=>{ all the rest of that, then setIoLabelsHide(newArr) and setIoLabelsShow(newArr)... but it sounds like forEach would be a better choice?

Comment: `map` is not what you want here. Use `forEach` or stick with your `for` loop. In any case ... you can use either of these with hooks. I'm not sure why you think you can't?

Comment: Oh i know you can, I'm just trying to make this bloated component less verbose. Next question, how do i use the iterator in a forEach? example, i need to get to ```data[i].id``` Same way?

Comment: It's the 2nd argument ... `array.forEach((item, index) => { ... })`. In your case I'd probably use a `for` loop though.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks a bunch!